# .exe doesnt show up on target machine

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, reference, installshield

I've coded an program, where following references are being used (already at the mainwindow)

Reference:

[image: References]

Now I have been using InstallShield-Wizard to create an setup.exe.

It is perfectly working at my computer, however at every other computer I have been trying it did not work. Nothing shows up after clicking the .exe file. I already have disabled the anti-virus, and already checked if the .NET Framework is higher than 4.5.

I think it is because the references aren't correctly included in the setup/.exe

Here are the configuartions I have used:

Requirements:

[image: Requirements]

Install Directory:

[image: InstallDirectory]

And this is how it looks like after it has been installed by the setup.exe:

[image: After Installation]

I dont know what do to.. Should I include the .dlls (MySQL, CrystalReport, Spire) in the InstallDirectory? I think there is somewhere a problem because of the references, as the mainwindow contains a grid which uses a MySQL reference..

Comment: Add some sort of logging, error handling in the mainwindow to see why it's not opening. Also as another test, copy all of the contents of the bin folder and place on another machine manually and verify that works.

Comment: Any reference which is marked as 'copy local' must be included in the setup. See if you have such references.

Comment: Is there anything helpful in the event log?

Comment: Ill try to add everything of the bin/debug folder manually.

Comment: @yossiz74 where do I have to look? I cant find anything :/

Comment: In Visual Studio, right click each reference > properties, and there is a property called 'Copy Local'. If it's set to True, it must be packaged together with your program.

Comment: @yossiz74 everything is set to true. As in the Installation Directory is every .dll file included, I dont know what could be wrong :/